# Foursquare api returns: The remote server returned an error(NotFound), webrequest on windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having a problem with my universal app, when running windows app
it works but when running the windows phone one it gives me some 
error saying: The remote server returned an 
error NotFound. I'm using foursquare api to search places nearby

string url = "http://api.foursquare.com/v2/vanues/search?ll=" + latitude + "," + longitude

```
 + "&radius=1000&limit=20&client_id=GEDT5VBHXZ0PASW3VQMHABRG0MQK2N41QNEJJNMWPOYZBEHZ&

     client_secret=Q5SHT204LFIZLPCJPFNTVVAOESYLWJPQ2MBQSKWCZ4D2XQWQ&v=20130815";

        WebRequest GETRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);

        GETRequest.Method = "GET";

        // TextBlk.Text = "Getting The Data.....";
         try
         {

            using (var GETResponse = await GETRequest.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                using (var GETResponseStream = GETResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(GETResponseStream);
                    string st = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    // TextBlk.Text = st;
                    JsonObject JO = JsonObject.Parse(st);
                    JsonObject obj = JO.GetNamedObject("response");

                    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {

                        JsonArray arr = obj.GetNamedArray("venues");
                        lastObj = arr.GetObjectAt(i);
                        JsonObject locationObject = lastObj.GetNamedObject("location");
                        lat = locationObject.GetNamedNumber("lat");
                        lan = locationObject.GetNamedNumber("lng");
                        Color c = Color.FromArgb(69, 5, 179, 156);

                        TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
                        t.Width = 300;
                        t.Text = lastObj.GetNamedString("name");
                        t.FontSize = 22;
                        t.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                        t.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        t.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                        var item = new GridViewItem { Background = new SolidColorBrush(c), Content = t, Width = 300, Height = 120, Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) };
                        gridview1.Items.Add(item);
                        mainProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                        mainProgressRing.IsActive = false;
                    }
                    gridview1.SelectionChanged += ListView_SelectionChanged;

                }
            }

        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            message = new MessageDialog(exception.Message);
        }

        await message.ShowAsync();
        //end of the web service receiving
    }
```

Comment: If you open the internet explorer on the device or emulator you are testing on can you browse to an internet page?  I am guessing you are not connected to the internet that is why you are getting a not found error.

Comment: I checked the internet it does connect, but now it pops up this dialog on visual studio. I can't upload a picture to show you but you can use this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/21mmq35xc3tupn9/error.png

Comment: The pdb file is the file where visual studio can get some info about your app when debugging.  I would clean the solution and try debugging again. I would also try different coordinates to make sure it just not 4 square not finding anything near the coordinates you are passing in

Comment: Thank you, it worked after I cleaned the project, you are my hero.